# How to check overrun?

Tags: stm32, uart, stm32f10x, hal-library

I'm using an STM32F103C8T6 (aka blue pill) with Eclipse/System Workbench and HAL.

The following code:

```
 volatile HAL_StatusTypeDef result =
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, bytesToSend + currentSendIndex, 
  bytesPerMessageToSend, 100);

 volatile uint32_t error = HAL_UART_GetError(&huart1);
```

works fine when sending 1 byte, and (later) receiving 1 byte and iterating this.

However, when sending 3 bytes, I noticed, I only receive the first byte, and the next calls for HAL_UART_Receive result in a timeout.

This seems logical, because probably there is only 1 byte buffer in the UART.

However, what I don't understand, why does transmitting multiple bytes in the code mentioned, returns HAL_OK, and also the call to HAL_UART_GetError returns 0.

I assume an overrun has occurred for the 2nd and consecutive bytes... is this true, and if yes, how can I check this?

Comment: Aren't you using TXempty for IRQ? What data rate?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Currently I'm not using interrupts, I will check into it this evening. It's 31,250 baud (MIDI), so quite slow.

Comment: Using a timer is possible to fill 8 byte data buffer  but IRQ is better. Before STM32 which have many std UARTS, I would use  IRQ with DMA to send bursts of data, so CPU could run processes, and do housekeeping and delgate the DMA. Make sure you use parity, and check for all errors, NE ORE or FE and test signal integrity for glitches.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I will try first the IRQ method, than DMA (never really used it, except for a blink example). I read that MIDI does not use parity so I 'cannot' use that.

Comment: For MIDI , I once just used the Joystick port to communicate over MIDI on WIN98

Comment: I think that was the default way in that time ... but I want to connect it to actual MIDI synthesizers, which have a DIN5 plug.

Comment: @Michel Keijzers if you want to learn microcontrollers forget HAL and use bare registers.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 I know it would be good to dive even deeper, but I'm already 'deeper' than I ever was. However, I think HAL is a great way to make the differences between all versions of STM32 less obvious. Of course a lot happens under the hood, but if I would have to write all those bar registers for all peripherals I'm planning to use (in future), I think my life ends earlier than my project finishes.

Comment: I bet that learning those ridiciolous HAL structures will be much more complicated and will take longer (now you have problem with very simple peripheral) , than learning the hardware itself. I cant help you as I know how the hardware works, but I have no clues what HAL does). I use some HAL libraries (strongly modified by me) especially for USB & Ethernet.

Comment: @Michel Keijzers BTW why HAL results are `volatile`?

Comment: @PeterJ_01 For one example, for polling (except for the problem above) it works using just a few of HAL functions. To dive into all base variables (which also change between various STM32)s would take much more effort I think. Although WHEN running into problems, diving deeper is a must, and in that case starting from the bare registers is probably better.

Comment: I made them volatile because otherwise they are optimized out, and during debugging it was the easiest way still to see them, just a very quick dirty hack (but good enough for a proof of concept).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure an interrupt to detect overrun errors. Actually a lot of interrupt are available to detect errors. From the [reference manual](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/59/b9/ba/7f/11/af/43/d5/CD00171190.pdf/files/CD00171190.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00171190.pdf):

[image]

Just for sure you could use the "Transmit data register empty" one as Tony has suggested.

As far as I know HAL IRQ handlers and IRQ calls for UART use all of these interrupts by default. The `_IT` versions of the UART calls enable all these interrupts.

Comment: Thanks ... I already knew interrupts would be better, but since I'm quite a newbie I thought it would be easier to start with the non-interrupt solution... But I guess I already found it's limitation. I will check interrupts, and yes, the HAL supports interrupts for UART.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution may end up duplicating existing products.

http://www.ucapps.de/mbhp_core_lpc17.html

Comment: I know such things exist, but first, I want to learn more about microcontrollers, but also I want eventually (at least) 4 inputs, 4 outputs and 4 thrus. Probably I could stack 4 of those.

Comment: Before you can design, you must know how everything works and fails, and learning curve depends on user.  So start with something that works.

Comment: Well I tried already a 'proof of concept' with 3 MIDI in/out/thrus on an Arduino and worked fine... but I need more memory, and possibly more processing power, so I am converting my proof of concept to STM32 ...

Comment: then you must use DMA for thruput in order to have useful functions.

Comment: Yes, but since I'm new I thought I start simple with polling, but that doesn't seem to work out well, so I will do IRQ/interrupts, and next step is using DMA.